# Problem with dynamic array in constructor, cannot convert char* to char

Tags: c++, class, constructor, dynamic-memory-allocation, incompatibletypeerror

I can't use string because of task conditions, so it must be char*. There is problem with dynamic array in constructor. Error "'=': cannot convert 'char*' to 'char'"

```
#include <iostream>

class Line {
public:
    const int Size = 10;
    char* DynamicLines = new char[Size];
    int counter = 0;

    Line(char* otherline) {
        if (counter < Size) {
            DynamicLines[counter] = otherline;
            counter++;
        }
        std::cout << "constructor called\n";
    }

    ~Line() {
        delete[] DynamicLines;
        std::cout << "destructor called\n";
    }

    void Print();
};

void Line::Print() {
    this->counter = 0;
    std::cout << DynamicLines[counter] << "\n" << "length = ";
    counter++;
}


void main()
{
    char* temp = new char;
    std::cin >> temp;
    Line Fline(temp);
    Fline.Print();
    delete temp;
        
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: What is the reason to dynamically allocate a single `char`? Why don't you pass it simply by value to the constructor? Another possible problem: `if (counter < Size)`. The condition is always true in the constructor.

Comment: what do you want to do? SHould the constructor take a single `char` or an array of char?

Comment: The error is obvious: `DynamicLines[counter] = otherline;` attempts to assign a `char*`  value to a `char` target. What is not whatsoever obvious is what the intent of that entire constructor is in the first place. And consider this: That's a *constructor*. Which means (a) `Size` is 10 (and always will be; it's const), *and* `counter` must be zero. Therefore explain the point of even testing `if (counter < Size)`, and for that matter, the rest of that constructor to [your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging),

Comment: It looks like what you're actually looking for is `char* DynamicLines [Size];` - an array of pointers to lines, all stored somewhere else.

Comment: This code is very confused between what is a line, and what is an array of lines. Then additionally you have that a line is an array of char. So you've just got yourself horribly confused about what is what. I would start again, and be very clear about what represents what. The best way to do that is by choosing descriptive names for classes and variables, This code would be so much easier for you if you used `std::string` and `std::vector`, but of course you're not allowed to do that.

Comment: As a example, having a class called `Line` which contains a data member called `DynamicLines` doesn't make any sense, the names just contradict each other. This leads to confusion or is symptomatic of confusion. Spend time to think about the names of things before you write the code that uses those names.

Comment: *I can't use string because of task conditions* -- `std::string` has been part of standard C++ for 24 years now, and also `std::vector` for that same amount of time.  Why do they teach C++ this way, with these ridiculous "task conditions"?  Using `std::string` would probably solve half of the issues you're having now.   Using these constructs, you still would need to write the program as `std::string` and `std::vector` will not magically write the program for you.  This is why so many programming students drop C++, and go directly to Java, C#, Python, or some other language.

Answer (score 3):

According to the C++ Standard the function main shall have the return type int

```
int main()
```

In this constructor

```
Line(char* otherline) {
    if (counter < Size) {
        DynamicLines[counter] = otherline;
        counter++;
    }
    std::cout << "constructor called\n";
}
```

this statement

```
DynamicLines[counter] = otherline;
```

does not make a sense. In the left hand side of the assignment there is an object of the type `char` while in the right hand side there is an object of the type `char *`. So the compiler issues the error message.

You need to copy elements of one array into another array.

Also the condition of this if statement

```
if (counter < Size) {
```

always evaluates to true. So the statement also does not make a sense.

And in main this code snippet can result in undefined behavior because you allocated only one character

```
char* temp = new char;
std::cin >> temp;
```

but are trying to enter a string.

Comment: I think OP tries to create array of strings, but code is a mess.

Comment: @Slava It is difficult to say because the code in whole does not make a sense.

Answer (score 0):

`char *DynamicLines` is pointer to an array of `char`. Therefore each entry in the array, is a `char`, not a `char*` (pointer).

Your constructor accepts a pointer to `char` which needs to be dereferenced, in order to access the `char` in the memory and store it in the array.

So:

```
Line(char* otherline) {
    if (counter < Size) {
        DynamicLines[counter] = *otherline; // Notice * in front, to get the value from the pointer
        counter++;
    }
    std::cout << "constructor called\n";
}
```

Comment: why use a pointer to a single char? If you stay with the pointer you'll need to fix `std::cin >> temp;` in `main` too

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number you are right. I focused on the compiler's error that is mentioned in the question (i.e. "cannot convert 'char*' to 'char'"). As Vlad from Moscow points out in his answer, OP's code has multiple issues that need to be fixed.